# How add minimum input string length as three for filter in autocomplete Box of material UI

Tags: reactjs, autocomplete, material-ui

I am trying to add a minimum input string length as three for the filter in autocomplete Box of material UI, My code is given below and it is not working properly. Anybody help me for solving these issues.

```
         const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState("");
         const filterOptions = ( options: string[],{ inputValue }: 
         FilterOptionsState<string>,) 
         => 
         {
         if (inputValue.length > 2) {
         return matchSorter(options, inputValue);
         } else {
         return [];
         }
       };

       <Autocomplete
             id={id}
             value={value}
             inputValue={inputValue}
             className={className}
             onInputChange={(event: React.ChangeEvent<any>) =>
             setInputValue(event?.target?.value)
             }
            classes={classes}
            onChange={handleChange}
            ListboxComponent={ListboxComponent}
            renderGroup={renderGroup}
            options={options || []}
            filterOptions={filterOptions}
            groupBy={(option) => option[0].toUpperCase()}
            renderInput={(params) => (
            <TextField {...params} variant="outlined" placeholder="Vendor name" />
            )}
           renderOption={(option) => {
           return (
           <>
             <Tooltip title={option} placement="right-end">
               <Typography noWrap>{option}</Typography>
             </Tooltip>
           </>
             );
             }}
               open={inputValue !== "" && inputValue?.length > 2}
              />;
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Similar - https://stackoverflow.com/a/74210236/1188322